# Ubuntu Kiosk Mode

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, cloud, kiosk, vdi

I’m workin on a ubuntu kiosk project but all contents are explaining browser-based scenario. Can you share some knowledge or resource about how can we use an aplication (such as word, excel, outlook etc.) on ubuntu kiosk mode?

Thanks

Comment: your example applications are windows applications, and not native GNU/Linux or Ubuntu applications.  You can use microsoft office (365) apps online using just a browser on any OS including Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit your question and include more details about your project. Share what you've done so far and explain what you need help with. If you are going to refer to another guide or question, for comparison or otherwise, you should link to that information and tell us how the link relates to your question.

Comment: Try the results of https://ubuntu.com/tutorials?q=kiosk . Also see https://snapcraft.io/install/ubuntu-frame/ubuntu

Comment: We will use linux native application. Actually, my application works on ubuntu and i dont want use the application with a browser. Can we execute the application directly as a kiosk mode?